# Rewrite Url (URL Routing) in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, directory, url-routing

My directories are like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/macbook-computer 
http://www.mydomain.com/sony-computer
http://www.mydomain.com/lenovo-computer
```

I want to make that, if a user type **computers/macbook-computer** like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/computers/macbook-computer
```

I want to display page which is :  `http://www.mydomain.com/macbook-computer`.

My restrictions are:

```
1. User must type /computers                                (segment 1)
2. String coming from computers/ must end with "computer".  (segment 2)
```

How can I make this achieve in my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/computers/([^-]+)-computer/? [NC]
RewriteRule .*  %1-computer?  [R=301,L]
```

Redirects permanently

`http://www.mydomain.com/computers/anyname-computer`  with or without trailing slash.

To:

`http://www.mydomain.com/anyname-computer`

Strings `computers` and `computer` are assumed to be fixed, while `anything` is assumed to be variable.

The incoming URL structure has to be kept for the rule-set to work: First folder `/computers` followed by `/anyname-computer`.

For silent mapping, remove `R=301` from `[R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

You need a rewrite rule in your .htaccess file, and a little regular expression magic. Something like this should do the trick

```
RewriteRule ^computers/macbook-computer$ http://www.mydomain.com/macbook-computer
```

Here's a nice online tool for checking rewrite rules

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/