# CodeIgniter URL Routing from `example.com/Partners/index.php/vendor` to `example.com/Partners`

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-3

I have a URL in codeigniter,

```
www.example.com/Partners/index.php/vendor
```

can I route it to `www.example.com/Partners`?

I need both URL to point to the same controller.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want that both of this urls point to the same controller?

Comment: You can change the .htacess. Check This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762536/rewrite-url-url-routing-in-htaccess

Comment: @marchiore yes i want both the URLs to point to same controller

Comment: @marchiore i did that but still no success. I am very new to PHP. Please help.

Comment: This is very easy in codeigniter. Just study basics before posting questions here. Check below url:- https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST SOLUTION**

If you don't have index method (function) in **parent** controller, you can make it and move all code from vendor to index method (function)

**SECOND SOLUTION**

- First thing is that **Parents** controller doesn't have index method
  (function).
- Second go to **application/config/routes** and add

  $route['partners '] = 'partners/index.php/vendor';